# Java scanner - Loop until the user provides a correct input

Tags: java, loops, exception, java.util.scanner

The desired behavior of the code is the following:
The user is asked for an input. While they provide incorrect input, they're asked again, until they finally enter a valid value.

Here is a minimal example:

```
int[] t = new int[2];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    try {
        int k = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(t[k]);
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

**(1)** If the user types "-1", the corresponding exception (namely "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 2") is printed, after what they have to type again (just as intended).

**(2)** However, if the user types "a", the corresponding exception (namely "java.util.InputMismatchException") is printed endlessly.

So, **can you explain why/how the Scanner class is causing the problem, and how to solve it?**

Answer (score 1):

(I figured out the answer while reviewing the question. Maybe this can help others)

Since an exception is raised by this instruction
`int k = scanner.nextInt();` 
this instruction is not completed, and hence, the "next" element of "System.in" is still the same (which is "a" in example **(2)**). Consequently, it raises the same exception endlessly.

To fix it, I simply had to add `scanner.nextLine();` in the *catch* statement, which causes the program to ask for a new user input.